# How to change the color for the scrollbar of a SurfaceScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How do I change the color of the scroll-bar in a WPF application which uses `SurfaceScrollViewer`?

Here an example of my control:

```
<Custom:SurfaceScrollViewer
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    Margin="40,20,30,0"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Height="345"
>
```

Comment: Have you tried nesting a Style for the ScrollBar ?

Comment: Could you provide me a sample please?